# Android Intrumented tests launch failed

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I'm trying to migrate my project from gradle 7.2 to gradle 8.2.
But the instrumented tests don't run anymore.

I've got this error :

```
":app:connectedDebugAndroidTest : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt".
```

This project must be developed on a private network without any Internet connection.